# Building a universal screencasting display/presenter: WiDi/MiraCast, ChromeCast, etc

Tags: wifi, display, screencasting, chromecast

I'm in the process of building a 2nd-screen solution for my workspace; something that provides ubiquitous connectivity, so that I can simply toggle any of my machines/mobiles/laptops/etc to use the screen on my desk as an additional monitor without needing to muck around with cables.

In W10+, there's an option to "cast/project to networked display", that uses the WiDi protocol, a variant of the Wi-Fi Direct standard.

Of course there's also the Chromecast protocol that seems fairly well integrated into modern-day browsers, though I'm not super familiar what a native protocol Linux/Unix/POSIX would use ([mkchromecast](https://mkchromecast.com/) is probably my best bet here).

For now I'm using an old RPi3b+ running stock *Bullseye* & *XFCE* driving little more than a terminal (to remote into headless hosts), *Midori* (lightweight browsing, but hardly use it due to the load it introduces) & *barrier* so that I only need to contend with a single set of input devices.

So far, so good.

Where I'm getting stuck on is using this (essentially thin client) as a rendering sink, i.e. being able to cast Video & Audio (AV) ***TO*** this device, rather than from it.

Now I know that this device hardware might simply not be capable of doing this (simple) rendering, so I have a NUC sitting spare for this purpose, i.e. once I've figured out the stack on the RPi, I can rebuild/redeploy it to this other box.

There really does not seem to be much for something that seems to common-place on the W32 ecosystem.
What I've found so far:

- [AirServer](https://www.airserver.com/) seems the simplest (best?) solution, but does not have a POSIX agent/renderer AFAICT
- [MiracleCast](https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast) & [LazyCast](https://github.com/homeworkc/lazycast) seem like promising solutions, but don't seem to work particularly well, even on other non-RPi machines I've tried.
- [GNOME Network Displays](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.gnome.NetworkDisplays) is close or essentially what I'm looking for, but lacks any meaningful documentation I can find

Across the board they all seem to rely on [WiFi-Direct](https://wiki.gnome.org/NetworkManager/WifiDirect) support on the sink, but that too is coming up lacking in the [RTFM-department](https://wiki.gnome.org/NetworkManager/WifiDirect). This protocol/stack seems somewhat ubiquitous, especially for embedded devices, but a total PITA on POSIX. The closest I've come to touch this end of the stack is around [wpa_supplicant](https://w1.fi/wpa_supplicant/) (& its associated wpa_cli & wpa_gui lower-level toolstools), but these are not yielding the results I'm looking for (such as the P2P config - PIBKAC)

I do have a few spare Android mobiles I would flash, but this will introduce a whole host of additional complexities I'd rather like to avoid & I'm not sure this'll improve the situation.

I'd appreciate any help that could be provided, as I'd like finish this off this build & put on the final touches.

Comment: this is a Q&A site ... not a brainstorming forum ... please adk a specific, answerable question

Comment: @jsotola - TL;DR: how can I use a Linux end-point (RasPi, NUC, etc) as a wireless display sink/renderer ala Chromecast, MiraCast, as available on virtually all other platforms?

The solutions & process outlined above has not yielded favourable results & asking for a way through or around the problem